# Получить значение из многомерного массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, foreach

Есть такой массив

```
Array
(
  [244] => Array
  (
    [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_02.jpg
    [goodImgAlt] => Infographics
    [goodGallery] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
        (
          [url] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_05.jpg
          [goodGalleryImgDescript] => Array
          (
            [0] => Array
            (
              [itemTitle] => Название
              [itemText] => Img 02
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
              [itemTitle] => Описание
              [itemText] => Копия
            )
          )
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
          [url] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_01.jpg
          [goodGalleryImgDescript] => Array
          (
            [0] => Array
            (
              [itemTitle] => Название
              [itemText] => Img 03
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
              [itemTitle] => Описание
              [itemText] => Img 03
            )
          )
        )
      )
  )
  [241] => Array
  (
    [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_01-1.jpg
    [goodImgAlt] => UX/UI design
    [goodGallery] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [url] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/slide_01-1.jpg
        [goodGalleryImgDescript] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
          (
            [itemTitle] => Название
            [itemText] => Img 03
          )
          [1] => Array
          (
            [itemTitle] => Описание
            [itemText] => Img 03
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  [234] => Array
  (
    [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_03.jpg
    [goodImgAlt] => Slide 2
  )
)
```

Массив goodsCardsArray получается таким вот образом:
Это на стороне php

```
echo json_encode($postParam);
```

Это после ajax запроса

```
success: function (response) {
  var goodsCardsArrayJson = response;
}

var goodsCardsArrayJson = response;
var goodsCardsArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(goodsCardsArrayJson));
```

Не работает когда вписываю forEach в еще один forEach

```
goodsCardsArray.forEach(item => {
  src = item.goodImgUrl;
  alt = item.goodImgAlt;
  goodGallery = item.goodGallery;
  goodGallery.forEach(item2 => {
    innerImgSrc = item2.url;
  });
});
```

Значения alt и src я достать могу а вот innerImgSrc я получить не могу.
Как получить значения из goodGallery и goodGalleryImgDescript?

JSON получается вот такой

```
{"244":{"goodImgUrl":"http:\/\/karvan\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/06\/thumb_02.jpg","goodImgAlt":"Infographics","goodGallery":[{"url":"http:\/\/karvan\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/06\/thumb_05.jpg","goodGalleryImgDescript":[{"itemTitle":"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435","itemText":"Img 02"},{"itemTitle":"\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435","itemText":"\u041a\u043e\u043f\u0438\u044f"}]},{"url":"http:\/\/karvan\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/06\/thumb_01.jpg","goodGalleryImgDescript":[{"itemTitle":"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435","itemText":"Img 03"},{"itemTitle":"\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435","itemText":"Img 03"}]}]}}
```

Comment: что значит не работает? Что ты хочешь в итоге получить?

Comment: Пишет такую вот ошибку VM281:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Мне нужно получить значения из goodGallery и goodGalleryImgDescript. Чтобы можно было вставить их в html. Пути к картинкам и текст к ним.

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь парсить то, что представлено в первом примере, то там не JSON. Откуда вы копируете такое представление архива?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt, похоже на вывод var_dump из php.

Comment: @Denis, без примера настоящего json, и примера результата можно только гадать что ты делаешь и что хочешь получить.

Comment: _Пишет такую вот ошибку VM281:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)_ - приведенный код не может дать такую ошибку. Следовательно проблема в другом месте.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Дописал подробнее что не получается. Почитайте выше.

Comment: @Denis, все еще неизвестно что у тебя на самом деле лежит в `goodsCardsArrayJson`

Comment: Добавил в вопросе json для элемента с индексом 244

Comment: выведи `console.log(item)` - что показывает?

Comment: {goodImgUrl: "http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_02.jpg", goodImgAlt: "Infographics", goodGallery: Array(2)}
goodGallery: Array(2)
0:
goodGalleryImgDescript: (2) [{…}, {…}]
url: "http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_05.jpg"
__proto__: Object
1:
goodGalleryImgDescript: (2) [{…}, {…}]
url: "http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_01.jpg"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
goodImgAlt: "Infographics"
goodImgUrl: "http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_02.jpg"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110313/discussion-between-grundy-and-denis).